# HTTP request after resolving DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, http

I'm looking at a device wireshark recording and see something weird.

After I completed the DNS resolve transaction (query + resonse),
I immediately get an HTTP response (200 OK) from the responding server.

the site is a standard public site: crl.verisign.net

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Did you verify the source and destination IPs/ports? Maybe, this is a response to an early request. We can not tell exactly what is happening from the provided information!

Comment: It's a mobile device, maybe something special that tells the server that if I DNS him, he should send something and avoid data consumption?

Answer (score 0):

CRL is Certificate Revocation List. It should be used by all SSL certificates (each cert contains an URL for CRL of its Certification Authority). Browser and any other program using the cert should first check the CRL list to see if the certificate has not been revoked in the meantime.
I don't know how the checking exactly works, but the HTTP response is probably for some earlier request, maybe for some other certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark allows you to follow the stream of a specific packet. If you do that, does it include the DNS lookup you referred to? Or is it possible that it's a response from a different stream, like others have mentioned?